# How can I configure tap-zones of touch-pad to map to a mouse button?

Tags: 16.04, mouse, touchpad, synaptics

Consider the following figure for the layout as explained in the manual by `man synaptics 4`:
[image: touch pad zones in Ubuntu]

I need to configure zone 2 to map to button 2 (middle click).

The manual says how to do this for zones 1, 3, 9 and 7 but not for 2, 4, 6, 8.

What I finally want:

- zone 2 should map to middle click (button 2)
- zone 9 should map to right click (button 3)
- everything else mapped to left click (button 1)
- vertical edge scrolling should work in zones 3, 6 and 9
- definitely no vertical edge scrolling in zone 2

I can figure out everything except the first one.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Too late, but I had the same problem after the Debian update to Bullseye.

From Archwiki (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Buttonless_touchpads_(aka_ClickPads)):

> In the following example the right button will occupy the rightmost 40% of the button area and the middle button 20% of it in the center. The leftmost 40% remains as a left button (as does the rest of the clickpad): 
>   `Option     "SoftButtonAreas"  "60% 0 82% 0 40% 59% 82% 0"`